# MvvmCross TitleText

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

The title of rows in table cells is set as follows.

```
var source = new MvxStandardTableViewSource(TableView, "TitleText FullName");
```

How is a subtitle text set along with the TitleText?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a standard cell type which has a subtitle, then you can use `DetailText` - see the property in [MvxStandardTableViewCell.cs#L73](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxStandardTableViewCell.cs#L73)

e.g.

```
 var source = new MvxStandardTableViewSource(
                       TableView, 
                       UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, 
                       "MyCellId", 
                       "TitleText FullName; DetailText Address");
```

Obviously the standard cell types are fairly limited in what they can display - for more advanced applications, it's best to switch to custom cell types. There are several articles and videos about how to do this - see http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com

Comment: Thank you Stuart, I greatly appreciate the help.  The constructor that appears to use the arguments that you are referring to takes in an NSString cellIdentifier.  Would you be able to explain this a bit further?

Comment: @Stuart how do i create a custom cell without XIBs or NIBs? I just want to define one in code

Comment: Try searching "Create custom MvxTableViewCell without NIB"? First hit was http://benjaminhysell.com/archive/2014/04/mvvmcross-custom-mvxtableviewcell-without-a-nib-file/

Comment: (To be fair, the same search with XIB didn't find the same site)

Comment: I was just coming back here to post a link to that article :-)